# WITH TIES not filtering the records based on record types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have written a sql to get the latest record which will based on version. It does pull the latest record but I need to ensure it pulls latest record of each type. The type is determined by AgreementId. As you can see in the snapshot below there are two records with different agreementIds. I am trying to use ties but that doesnt seem to work. What am i doing wrong

These are the current records

[image]

The Query below gets only one record that is latest agreement from the two records. Ideally it should be returning both as they are two types of agreement .  I am using WITH TIES but that doesn't seem to be doing what i want

```
  SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES  ua.ID AS UserAgreementID ,
         A.ID AS AgreementID ,
         A.Code ,
         A.ComplianceCode ,
         A.Name ,
         A.Description ,
         A.Version ,
         ua.UserAgreementStateID ,
         uas.Name AS UserAgreementStateName ,
         ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry ,
         declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry) AS TimeLeft ,
         A.Data ,
         pa.ID AS AuthoredByID ,
         pa.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS AuthoredByName ,
         A.Authored ,
         ia.ID AS IssuedByID ,
         ia.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS IssuedByName ,
         A.Issued
  FROM declaration.Agreement AS A
  INNER JOIN declaration.UserAgreement AS ua ON A.ID = ua.AgreementID
  INNER JOIN declaration.UserAgreementState AS uas ON ua.UserAgreementStateID = uas.ID
  LEFT JOIN common.Person AS pa ON A.AuthoredBy = pa.ID
  LEFT JOIN common.Person AS ia ON A.IssuedBy = ia.ID WHERE ua.UserID = 607
  AND uas.Code IN ('ISS',
                   'DEF','EXP')-- Issued, Deferred

  AND A.Draft = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not a draft.

  AND A.Deleted = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not deleted.

  AND (A.Issued <= GETUTCDATE()
       OR A.Issued IS NULL)
  AND (A.Expires > GETUTCDATE()
       OR A.Expires IS NULL)
ORDER BY A.Version DESC
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: WITH TIES considering A.Version...

Comment: You could use a window function.

Comment: I need to pull latest version of each agreement type

Comment: So as per my current records the query should pull both the records

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want:

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.AgreementID ORDER BY A.Version DESC)
```

The `row_number()` function ranks records having the same `AgreementID` by descending `Version`. In other words, for each `AgreementID`, the function assigns rank `1` to the record that has the greatest `Version`. Then, `TOP (1) WITH TIES` filters on all records that are ranked first.